# How to round image inside svg

Tags: svg, svg-filters, jquery-svg

I create an image inside a svg but want to round it and fill the shape (small circle). 
I already did image round in html image tag using css style but not know how i can do it in side a svg or apply same css style in svg. Here is a code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<style>
.pic-circle-corner {
display: block;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
/*   margin: .8em auto; */
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 5px ; /* solid #eee*/
box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 }

</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div> picture should fill inside round shape..
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-  background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
<filter id="this_image" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feImage   width="28px" height="28px"   xlink:href="http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/1/WDF_499177.jpg"/>
</filter>
<circle cx="46" cy="42" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"  filter="url(#this_image)"  />
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#026890"  d="M35.686,13.595c-0.172-1.381-0.541-2.705-1.085-3.979
    c-0.517-1.208-1.19-2.327-1.995-3.37c-0.758-0.982-1.629-1.855-2.593-2.629c-1.124-0.901-2.359-1.633-3.688-2.197
    c-1.44-0.613-2.941-1.011-4.497-1.179c-2.306-0.252-4.575-0.041-6.787,0.672c-1.006,0.324-1.975,0.741-2.896,1.261
    c-1.782,1.007-3.32,2.295-4.606,3.889C6.355,7.53,5.472,9.165,4.893,10.956c-0.397,1.23-0.63,2.498-0.694,3.793
    c-0.057,1.153-0.017,2.301,0.175,3.438c0.158,0.944,0.415,1.866,0.749,2.767c0.369,0.994,0.842,1.938,1.434,2.815
    c0.666,0.986,1.373,1.944,2.053,2.921c1.443,2.076,10.465,12.023,11.379,13.173c1.063-1.314,10.533-11.896,13.064-15.517
    c0.96-1.372,1.713-2.839,2.175-4.453c0.242-0.849,0.427-1.708,0.52-2.586C35.875,16.068,35.84,14.832,35.686,13.595z M20,28.318
    c-7.041,0-12.75-5.709-12.75-12.751S12.958,2.817,20,2.817c7.042,0,12.75,5.708,12.75,12.75S27.042,28.318,20,28.318z"/>
</svg>

 </div>
 <div style="padding-top:50px;">
 <image class="pic-circle-corner"  src="http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/1/WDF_499177.jpg">
 </div>



  </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Can someone tell me a correct way.

Comment: clip the image using a clipPath that contains a circle element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these are some options:

**1) absolute position -** place the SVG path inside a container and place an absolute positioned circled div with a background image on top of the path.

HTML/SVG:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle-div"> </div>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
     <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#026890"  d="M35.686,13.595c-0.172-1.381-0.541-2.705-1.085-3.979
        c-0.517-1.208-1.19-2.327-1.995-3.37c-0.758-0.982-1.629-1.855-2.593-2.629c-1.124-0.901-2.359-1.633-3.688-2.197
        c-1.44-0.613-2.941-1.011-4.497-1.179c-2.306-0.252-4.575-0.041-6.787,0.672c-1.006,0.324-1.975,0.741-2.896,1.261
        c-1.782,1.007-3.32,2.295-4.606,3.889C6.355,7.53,5.472,9.165,4.893,10.956c-0.397,1.23-0.63,2.498-0.694,3.793
        c-0.057,1.153-0.017,2.301,0.175,3.438c0.158,0.944,0.415,1.866,0.749,2.767c0.369,0.994,0.842,1.938,1.434,2.815
        c0.666,0.986,1.373,1.944,2.053,2.921c1.443,2.076,10.465,12.023,11.379,13.173c1.063-1.314,10.533-11.896,13.064-15.517
        c0.96-1.372,1.713-2.839,2.175-4.453c0.242-0.849,0.427-1.708,0.52-2.586C35.875,16.068,35.84,14.832,35.686,13.595z M20,28.318
        c-7.041,0-12.75-5.709-12.75-12.751S12.958,2.817,20,2.817c7.042,0,12.75,5.708,12.75,12.75S27.042,28.318,20,28.318z"/>
        </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.circle-div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url('http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/1/WDF_499177.jpg');
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 25% 25%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5px;
  top: 2.5px;
}
```

---

**2) SVG clipPath** - place an SVG image on top the SVG path and clip it with a circle.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <defs>
        <clipPath  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clip">
          <circle cx="50%" cy="40%" r="13" ></circle>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>

        <image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" clip-path="url(#clip)" x="5" y="2" width="100%" height="65%" xlink:href="http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/1/WDF_499177.jpg"></image> 
            <path stroke-width="1px" stroke="#026890" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#026890"  d="M35.686,13.595c-0.172-1.381-0.541-2.705-1.085-3.979
        c-0.517-1.208-1.19-2.327-1.995-3.37c-0.758-0.982-1.629-1.855-2.593-2.629c-1.124-0.901-2.359-1.633-3.688-2.197
        c-1.44-0.613-2.941-1.011-4.497-1.179c-2.306-0.252-4.575-0.041-6.787,0.672c-1.006,0.324-1.975,0.741-2.896,1.261
        c-1.782,1.007-3.32,2.295-4.606,3.889C6.355,7.53,5.472,9.165,4.893,10.956c-0.397,1.23-0.63,2.498-0.694,3.793
        c-0.057,1.153-0.017,2.301,0.175,3.438c0.158,0.944,0.415,1.866,0.749,2.767c0.369,0.994,0.842,1.938,1.434,2.815
        c0.666,0.986,1.373,1.944,2.053,2.921c1.443,2.076,10.465,12.023,11.379,13.173c1.063-1.314,10.533-11.896,13.064-15.517
        c0.96-1.372,1.713-2.839,2.175-4.453c0.242-0.849,0.427-1.708,0.52-2.586C35.875,16.068,35.84,14.832,35.686,13.595z M20,28.318
        c-7.041,0-12.75-5.709-12.75-12.751S12.958,2.817,20,2.817c7.042,0,12.75,5.708,12.75,12.75S27.042,28.318,20,28.318z"/>

</svg>
```

---

**3) SVG pattern** - place an SVG circle on top  the SVG path and fill it with a pattern that is the image itself.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <defs>
       <pattern  id="pf" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%"
             viewBox="0 0 960 420" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice">
      <image x="-150" y="11" width="960" height="420" xlink:href="http://pic.1fotonin.com/data/wallpapers/1/WDF_499177.jpg" ></image>
    </pattern>
    </defs>

    <circle cx="50%" cy="40%" r="13"  fill="url(#pf)"></circle>
        <path stroke-width="1px" stroke="#026890" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#026890"  d="M35.686,13.595c-0.172-1.381-0.541-2.705-1.085-3.979
    c-0.517-1.208-1.19-2.327-1.995-3.37c-0.758-0.982-1.629-1.855-2.593-2.629c-1.124-0.901-2.359-1.633-3.688-2.197
    c-1.44-0.613-2.941-1.011-4.497-1.179c-2.306-0.252-4.575-0.041-6.787,0.672c-1.006,0.324-1.975,0.741-2.896,1.261
    c-1.782,1.007-3.32,2.295-4.606,3.889C6.355,7.53,5.472,9.165,4.893,10.956c-0.397,1.23-0.63,2.498-0.694,3.793
    c-0.057,1.153-0.017,2.301,0.175,3.438c0.158,0.944,0.415,1.866,0.749,2.767c0.369,0.994,0.842,1.938,1.434,2.815
    c0.666,0.986,1.373,1.944,2.053,2.921c1.443,2.076,10.465,12.023,11.379,13.173c1.063-1.314,10.533-11.896,13.064-15.517
    c0.96-1.372,1.713-2.839,2.175-4.453c0.242-0.849,0.427-1.708,0.52-2.586C35.875,16.068,35.84,14.832,35.686,13.595z M20,28.318
    c-7.041,0-12.75-5.709-12.75-12.751S12.958,2.817,20,2.817c7.042,0,12.75,5.708,12.75,12.75S27.042,28.318,20,28.318z"/>

</svg>
```

---

I think the easiest solution in this case is to go with CSS, as it requires less position-tweaking to get proper results.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bozz1/mvsbn2cb/1/)